# XMBC Flicks missing from plugin list

Tags: kodi, netflix

I have just installed XBMC on a Windows XP machine, and would like to use it to play Netflix. The XBMC Flicks plugin is not in the list of video plugins.

The version of XBMC is 11 (Eden). The machine has Silverlight and Internet Explorer (I have used this machine to play Netflix via IE).

Any ideas why the plugin would not be listed, or if there is another way to play Netflix via XBMC?

Comment: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=87552 one-platform one-country plugin.... i prefer danish tv instead...

Comment: Yes, this is the plugin that I'm trying to install. This page says that it should be listed in the XBMC plugin repo. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download the latest version of xbmcFlicks

  https://github.com/spudsdude/XBMC-Flicks/zipball/master
- Extract to XBMC's addons directory -->

  ***Windows 7 \ Vista:*** C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\XBMC\addons

  ***Windows XP:***        C:\Documents and Settings\yourUsername\Application
  Data\XBMC\addons
- Start/restart XBMC & look in your video addons..

Comment: Thanks! Almost perfect... in Windows XP the location is C:\Documents and Settings\YourUser\Application Data\XBMC\addons

Comment: Totally forgot about the XP... Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on [the 66th page of the thread](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=87552&pid=981367#pid981367):

> i'm still sorting out some changes that are needed for eden

So I guess the answer is "just wait".